# How to dynamically add components to NgModule in Angular 4 and @angular/cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a way to add components to the declarations and entryComponents attribute dynamically (Angular 4, angular/cli 1.1.2)?

Background: I created an AppInfo.ts where developers can define additional components that will be loaded dynamically using ComponentFactoryResolver (something like widgets).
This AppInfo.ts consists of an static array of components (AppInfo.components) .

How can I push elements of this array to the NgModule Decorator?

I got this solution that does work using ng serve but not using ng build --prod:

```
export const ngmodule = {
  declarations: [...],
  entryComponents:[ ],
  imports: [...],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [...]
};

for (let i = 0; i < AppInfo.components.length; i++) {
  const comp = <any> AppInfo.components[i];
  ngmodule.entryComponents.push(comp);
  ngmodule.declarations.push(comp);
}

@NgModule(ngmodule)
```

If I try to build my app using ng build --prod I get this error:

> ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class DynCompExample in /Users/x/Documents/x/src/app/x/x/DynCompExample.component.ts! Add DynCompExample to the NgModule to fix it.

But if I use ng serve It works fine.

Comment: Why not just write `entryComponents:[AppInfo.components],`?

Comment: I don't think you can you a *const* variable passed to @NgModule. The production build doesn't run the module file, but scans it to extract metadata for ahead of time compiling. Therefore it doesn't know what to do in your above code. I think it explains this in the documents.

Comment: @echonax
My AppInfo.components isn't just an array of components. It's of type {name:string, component:Component}[]. I made this example easier to understand.

Comment: You can kind of do this with providers. Look at the router and `forRoot` as an example, but components are another issue. Since they have templates the AOT compile needs to find them, and compile the templates.

Comment: Also, you should only need 1 entry component. Pushing many components into that array will slow down the app start up.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia thank you for your comments. Is there a better way to achieve my goal? A way to offer developers to easily add their components to AppInfo (without changing NgModule directly). In my situation I can't let developers add the components directly.

Comment: See if you can do the build with AOT turned off: ng build -prod -aot=false

Comment: @YakovFain yes this works. Is there a way to get it working without this parameter?

Comment: I don't know. This just proves that the AOT compiler (ngc) doesn't understand your code while compiling templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is export an array of components and use that in `@NgModule`

You can split this between internal components, and developer components.

**Internal.components.ts**

```
export const INTERNAL_COMPONENTS = [
       FooterComponent,
       HeaderComponent,
       SideBarComponent
];
```

**Developer.components.ts**

```
export const DEVELOPER_COMPONENTS = [
       WidgetComponent,
       CustomerComponent,
       NewFeatureComponent
];
```

Then you import those into your module file and use them.

```
import {INTERNAL_COMPONENTS} from './Internal.components.ts';
import {DEVELOPER_COMPONENTS} from './Developer.components.ts';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        INTERNAL_COMPONENTS,
        DEVELOPER_COMPONENTS
    ],
    exports: [
        INTERNAL_COMPONENTS,
        DEVELOPER_COMPONENTS
    ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Leave the entry component as a single main component.